# Completely Disable Module - Magento 1.9

Tags: xml, module, configuration, magento-1.9

I am trying to disable a Magento module programatically. For just trying I added the following code to myadmin **header.phtml**.

```
    // Disable the module itself
    $moduleName="Thycart_Customcheckout"
        $nodePath = "modules/$moduleName/active";
        if (Mage::helper('core/data')->isModuleEnabled($moduleName)) {
            Mage::getConfig()->setNode($nodePath, 'false', true);
            echo Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/Thycart_Customcheckout')->active;            
        }

        // Disable its output as well (which was already loaded)
         $outputPath = "advanced/modules_disable_output/$moduleName";
         if (!Mage::getStoreConfig($outputPath)) {
             Mage::app()->getStore()->setConfig($outputPath, true);
         }
```

**On echoing**

> Mage::getConfig()->getNode('modules/Thycart_Customcheckout')->active;

is returning me its false but actualy the module is not getting disabled from xml.

**Also tried**

> Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig();

**returned a**

> Front controller reached 100 router match iterations Error.

Can someone please help to make the node active to false in config file . Thanks.

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/48840/46038

Comment: @BachchaSingh that is not programmatic

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad practice of code. You should not disable module like this. When your phtml file (header.php) executes, most of the module are already called the they have their objects in memory.

If you want to disable module then you can disable them by 
system->configuration->advance->disable modules output or you can disable them by

setting false in their modules .xml file in \app\etc\modules\Mynamespace_Mymodulename.xml .